# How to show Flalist in 3 columns if their is an condition applying for it in react-native?

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I'd a list where more then 2 categories and you can see the layout of it. Basically when comes the first on 'ALL' categories for first tab, it appears properly but after it it goes in 2 columns/1 column layout.

This is the first tab and other tabs should be like this in 3 columns:
[image]

& this is the other tabs look like (this should be look like the above layout).
[image]

**Here is the full code of the program:
[PLEASE CLICK HERE](https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/supportive-apple)**